# How can I set 'no-tty' for 'stack sdist' without disabling it for 'gpg' in general?

Tags: cabal, gnupg, haskell-stack

If I run

```
stack sdist --sign ...
```

I get

```
Error signing with GPG 
gpg: cannot open `/dev/tty': Device not configured
```

[unless I place](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/5065#issuecomment-207960831)

```
no-tty
```

in my `~/.gnupg/gpg.conf`.

But if I do that then

```
gpg -e ...
```

gives

```
gpg: Sorry, no terminal at all requested - can't get input
```

Is there a way to configure `gpg` or `stack sdist` so that I can use `no-tty` for the latter but not the former? For example can I use a local `gpg.conf` in the projects where I run `stack sdist`? Or are there command line args I can provide to either `gpg` or `stack sdist` that will have the same effect? Perhaps there is a way to pass `--no-tty` through `stack sdist` to the underlying GPG?

---

As an added constraint, I need this to work in an IDE where I am limited to a single shell command (so I can't batch this or write a small script to do it):

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [source code of stack's GnuPG interface](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/blob/ead648fae5ed2369b5d7b2cd28b86dc69b208486/src/Stack/Sig/GPG.hs), there is no possibility in stack to add GnuPG parameters:

```
(_hIn,hOut,hErr,process) <-
    gpg
        [ "--output"
        , "-"
        , "--use-agent"
        , "--detach-sig"
        , "--armor"
        , toFilePath path]
```

Given having Microsoft add support for a proper TTY variable is not realistic, you're probably best off having stack changed. I'd consider not providing `--no-tty` as GnuPG parameter if stack's `--no-terminal` parameter is set a bug. Additionally, some way to pass custom options to GnuPG seems a reasonable thing to support and feature request.

As a workaround, you should very well be able to provide some kind of wrapper batch script around `stack --sign`. A possible solution would be to set a `GNUPGHOME` environment variable pointing to a stack-specific copy of your GnuPG home directory, that includes `no-tty` as a configuration option (so you have a "default" GnuPG home directory for day-to-day work, and a specific one for code signing). You might also be able to provide such an environment variable in the IDE.

Comment: The alternate GNUPGHOME is a good option, otherwise using a script wrapper to comment/uncomment the `no-tty` line in the `$GNUPGHOME/gpg.conf` would be a "simple" way to tweak the behavior temporarily.